# Quais são as regras para o uso da vírgula?

Tags: gramática, vírgula

Quais são as regras para o uso da vírgula em uma frase?

Já ouvi várias explicações sobre como usá-la, mas ainda não consegui definir um padrão. Já ouvi também, que existem mais de 10 "regrinhas" para usá-la. Quais são elas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada guia de estilo diverge quanto ao uso da vírgula, discordando do senso comum em menor ou maior grau. Um dos tópicos de divergência mais famosos é [o uso da vírgula antes do último item de uma enumeração](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). Enquanto alguns guias de estilo requerem a vírgula antes de uma conjunção coordenada (e.g. "*França, Suíça, e Itália*"), outros não requerem-no (e.g., "*França, Suíça e Itália*"). Eis alguns guias de estilo:

- [Lexikon](http://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap19-01-sinais_que_marcam_sobretudo_a_pausa);
- [Manual de Estilo da Presidência do Brasil](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/manual/ManualRedPR2aEd.PDF), que na pg.
  61 permite que o sujeito seja separado do predicado em casos
  específicos;
- [Só Português](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono30.php).

A vírgula basicamente separa coisas. Tal mecanismo de separação funciona mais ou menos assim:

- Uma única vírgula separa dois elementos:

  > Mal fui**,** e já voltei.
- Um par de vírgulas possui função ambígua. Pode ou separar 3 elementos uns dos outros ou separar um elemento interno do restante que comporta-se como uma única coisa. Por exemplo:

  > "*Vim**,** vi**,** venci.*" (Nesse caso, a vírgula está separando 3 elementos).
  >
  > "*Elisabeth**,** rainha da Inglaterra**,** está viajando*" (Nesse caso, a vírgula está separando o elemento interno do restante).

  A vírgula nesses exemplos poderiam ser substituídas por ponto-e-vírgula, no primeiro, e pela eliminação do elemento interno, no segundo, desambiguando e mantendo a sintaxe:

  > *"Vim**;** vi**;** venci.*"
  >
  > *"Elisabeth está viajando."*

### Frases coordenadas

A vírgula é usada para separar orações coordenadas onde nenhuma é precedida por conjunção; para separar orações coordenadas onde todas são precedidas por conjunção; para separar frases nominais (vocativos, interjeições, etc.) entre si; e para separar frases nominais e uma oração:

- "*Vim, vi, venci.*" — Separação de três orações coordenadas, nenhuma precedida por conjunção.
- "*Você tinha razão, o problema estava no motor do carro*." — Separação de duas orações coordenadas, nenhuma precedida por conjunção.
- "*Ou você ama, ou você odeia, ou você ignora*." — Separação de três orações coordenadas, todas precedidas por conjunção.
- "*Essa linda mulher dominou meu coração, e que mulher!*" — Separação de uma oração e uma frase nominal exclamativa.
- "*Boa sorte, meu amigo.*" — Separação de uma frase nominal desirativa (*boa sorte*) e uma frase nominal vocativa (*meu amigo*)
- "*Então, você vem me ver hoje?*" — Separação de uma frase nominal interjectiva (*então*) e uma oração.
- "*Filho, já pensaste no que quer ser?*" — Separação de uma frase nominal vocativa (*filho*) e uma oração.
- "*Gostou da blusa?
  Sim, eu adorei!*" — No segundo período, há a separação de uma frase nominal interjectiva (*sim*) e uma oração. "*Sim*" e "*não*" são advérbios, mas quando usados como único elemento de uma frase para resposta, comportam-se como interjeição.

No caso de orações coordenadas em que apenas a última oração é precedida por conjunção, as regras de uso da vírgula variam. No geral, todas as orações exceto a última são obrigatoriamente separadas por vírgula, a última pode ser separada dependendo do guia de estilo em uso:

- "*Aproveite, divirta-se e comemore*" vs. "*aproveite, divirta-se, e comemore*".
- "*Todo humano nasce, cresce e morre*" — Muitos guias de estilo optam por não separar a última oração por vírgula, quando todas as orações coordenadas compartilham o mesmo sujeito.

Em alguns casos, uma das frases pode ocorrer dentro da outra; um fenómeno chamado "parêntese" (a figura de linguagem, não o sinal gráfico). Nesse caso, a vírgula é usada para separar a frase interna daquela onde está contida:

- "*Essa linda mulher, e que mulher, dominou meu coração!*".
- "*O problema, você tinha razão, estava no motor do carro*."
- "*Já pensaste, filho, no que quer ser?*".

### Termos coordenados

A vírgula é usada para separar termos sintaticamente equivalentes (i.e., que possuem a mesma função sintática) que estejam coordenados (ou repetidos).

- "*Maria, Paulo, e Artur foram passear.*" — Separação de sujeitos coordenados.
- "*Viajarei Terça, Quarta, ou Sexta.*" — Separação de advérbios coordenados.
- "*Sua pele ficou vermelha, vermelha de tanto tomar sol*". — Separação das repetições de um predicativo do sujeito.

Diferentes guias de estilo possuem diferentes regras quanto à separação de termos coordenados. Enquanto uns usam a vírgula para separar todos os elementos, outros não usam a vírgula antes da conjunção. A frase "*Maria, Paulo, e Artur foram passear*" pode ser reescrita como "*Maria, Paulo e Artur foram passear*" (sem a vírgula antes do *"e"*).

Note que, ao separar verbos por vírgula você está criando duas orações, e portanto cai no caso especificado pela seção anterior (Frases coordenadas):

- "*Eu plantei, colhi e preparei cada flor.*" — Separação de 3 verbos e, consequentemente, de 3 orações, que compartilham o mesmo sujeito (e possivelmente o mesmo complemento verbal, mas isso depende da interpretação).

### Termos essenciais da oração

Como norma geral, não deve-se separar termos essenciais uns dos outros. Ou seja, não deve-se separar o sujeito, verbo (ou locução verbal) e predicativo por vírgula. Porém, note que pode sim haver vírgulas entre o sujeito e o predicado, quando há entre eles algo que é separado dos demais, tal como no exemplo anterior:

- "*Elisabeth, rainha da Inglaterra, está viajando.*" — Correto.
  "*Elisabeth, está viajando.*" — Errado.
  "*Elisabeth está viajando.*" — (Igual à anterior, mas sem vírgula) Correto.
- "*Pedro é, como todos dizem, iteligentíssio.*" — Correto.
  "*Pedro é, inteligentíssimo.*" — Errado.
  "*Pedro é inteligentíssimo.*" — (Igual à anterior, mas sem vírgula) Correto.

### Complementos verbais

Os complementos do verbo (objeto direto, objeto indireto, agente da passiva) são separados dos demais quando apresentados em posições diferentes da ordem direta. Por exemplo:

- *"Meu livro, você trouxe?"* vs. *"Você trouxe meu livro?"*.
- *"Por Aristóteles, Alexandre Magno foi educado"* vs. *"Alexandre Magno foi educado por Aristóteles"*.

### Adjuntos adverbiais

Adjuntos adverbiais são geralmente livres, e o uso da vírgula para separá-los do restante da frase é arbitrário. Certas locuções adverbiais explicativas ("*isto é*", "*por exemplo*", "*ou seja*", etc.) e suas abreviações ("*i.e.*", "*p.ex.*", etc.) são separados por vírgula, tal como consagradas pelo uso. Por exemplo:

- "*Essa escola, com toda certeza, está falida*" vs. "*Essa escola com toda certeza está falida*". — Ambos corretos.
- "*Quando crescer, quero ser forte*" vs. "*Quando crescer quero ser forte*". — Ambos corretos.
- "*Fique, porém, conosco*" vs. "*Fique porém conosco*". — Ambos corretos, embora o primeiro seja mais aceito.
- "*Não existe, em todo continente, espécime tão bem preservado*" vs. "*Não existe em todo continente espécime tão bem preservado*". — Ambos corretos, embora o primeiro seja mais aceito.

### Aposto

O aposto restritivo não é separado do restante da frase por vírgula, mas o aposto explicativo é. Note que o uso da vírgula definirá se um aposto é restritivo ou explicativo. Por exemplo:

- "*O poeta português **Fernando Pessoa** tinha vários pseudónimos*". — "*Fernando Pessoa*" é um aposto restritivo, portanto não é separado por vírgula.
- "*Fernando Pessoa, **poeta português**, tinha vários pseudónimos*" — "*Poeta português*" é um aposto explicativo, portanto é separado por vírgula.
- "*A árvore florida, **que Pedro cultivou**, faleceu anteontem*". — "*Que Pedro cultivou*" é uma oração apositiva explicativa, portanto é separada por vírgula.
- "*A árvore florida **que Pedro cultivou** faleceu anteontem*". — "*Que Pedro cultivou*" é uma oração apositiva restritiva, portanto não é separada por vírgula.

### Notações

O uso de vírgula em notações de títulos, números, cabeçalhos, etc. é a que mais está sujeita a regulação divergente por guias de estilo:

- `10,055` (Dez inteiros e cinquenta e cinco milésimos) — Vírgula como separador decimal.
- `10,055` (Dez mil e cinquenta e cinco) — Vírgula como separador de milhares.
- `Roma, 17 de Julho de 2017`. — Datação.